# Getting error - Could not locate the bindings file. Tried: node_expat (ubuntu)

Tags: node.js

```
{ Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/build/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/build/Debug/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project//node_modules/node-expat/out/Debug/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/Debug/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/out/Release/node_expat.node
 → /home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/Release/node_expat.node
 at bindings (/home/Project/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Project/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Project/node_modules/xml2json/lib/xml2json.js:1:13)
```

**node version - v10.24.1
npm version - 6.14.12**

I tried to delete node_module folder and installed packages again still not output.
Also, tried to install node-expat again using *npm install node-expat* no output.
Also, used command such as *$ npm install node-gyp@latest* and *npm install libxmljs@0.11.0* still same error.

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you get solutions??

Comment: Yes! I used node version 14 then it perfectly worked for me